# open() call path error

Tags: c, file-io, system, call

I am having issues with the input of open If my first argument is a path I get this output:

> Error en open: No such file or directory

but if its file name there is no error, how can in fix it? The code is as follows:

```
#include<sys/types.h>   //Primitive system data types for abstraction of implementation-dependent data types.
                        //POSIX Standard: 2.6 Primitive System Data Types <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>

char buf1[]="abcdefghij";
char buf2[]="ABCDEFGHIJ";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int fd;
if( (fd=open(argv[1],O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR))<0) {
    printf("\nError %d en open",errno);
    perror("\nError en open");
    exit(-1);
}
if(write(fd,buf1,10) != 10) {
    perror("\nError en primer write");
    exit(-1);
}

if(lseek(fd,40,SEEK_SET) < 0) {
    perror("\nError en lseek");
    exit(-1);
}

if(write(fd,buf2,10) != 10) {
    perror("\nError en segundo write");
    exit(-1);
}

return 0;
}
```

The test sequence is:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/pablo/...# ./tarea1 /home/pablo/hello > temp ; cat temp
root@ubuntu:/home/pablo/...# ./tarea1 /home/pablo/>hello ; cat hello 
Error en open: Is a directory
```

Comment: What do you mean by "path"? The name of a directory?

Comment: It is not safe to call `printf` before `perror`.  If there is an error during `printf`, it will overwrite `errno` and the error printed by `perror` will refer to the `printf` error rather than the `open` error.  If there is no error during the `printf`, it is possible (depending on implementation) that `printf` will modify `errno`.

Comment: It works here. Maybe you supplied no argv[1], or a nonexisting path, or a path where you have no access to in argv[1] or a path which is only a derectory, with no filename at the end ? (I used `./a.out the_file` )

Comment: Arkku by "path" I mean directory with the name of the file that i want the code creates, i have tried create the file in home in a directory that already exists so and i am working as root so i dont think its the problem

Comment: It should be a filename, not a directory name. (could be a nonexistant filenam, but you must be able to create it there)

Comment: if i use opendir that's is the output abcdefghij
Error en lseek: Illegal seek

Comment: You're a brave man using `root` privileges while you're learning to program.  I hope you've got a good backup system in place and have tested the recovery.  Generally speaking, don't do program development as `root`, and don't do program testing as `root` if you can help it.  It is far too easy to wreck your whole system by accident.

Comment: "*how can in fix it?*": fix what? What are you trying to achieve? Tell us what's the purpose of the action failing.

Answer (score 0):

Your second test sequence is:

```
# ./tarea1 /home/pablo/>hello
```

This would be more clearly written as:

```
# ./tarea1 /home/pablo/ >hello
```

The shell gives your program the name of a directory, `/home/pablo/`, and creates a file `hello` in the current directory.  Any standard output from your program goes to the file.  When your program tries to open the directory for writing, it fails — not even `root` is allowed to write in a directory.  (You can open a directory for reading, but can't actually read from it; that's useful for the various `*at()` functions (such as [`openat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html)), but not otherwise.)

If you really want a `>` in your file name, enclose the whole name in quotes:

# ./tarea1 "/home/pablo/>hello"

However, you don't really want a `>` in your file name; it just makes life difficult (not quite as bad as a newline in the file name, but close).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said whether you're using Linux or not.  But I'm going to guess you are.

Linux open has this really annoying feature that for some reason the file doesn't already exist and you use the version of open that  doesn't have the third mode parameter, it fails to create the file.  At least that's what I've found.  If however the file does exist and has the appropriate permissions, the 2 parameter open call should succeed.

The fix is to change the open call to:

```
fd=open(argv[1],O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR, S_IRWXU)
```

By the way, I hope you're aware that the program will pass null to the open call if there are no parameters.